# How can I calculate the following integral (partial fractions)?

Tags: calculus, integration

$ \int_{\frac{3}{2}}^{2} \sqrt\frac{x-1}{3-x}\,dx$

I tried to integrate at first with $u= \sqrt \frac{x-3}{x-1}$ and after it I get a very complicated integration by partial fractions, can I solve it with an other way too? I think it has to be a much easier method, I appreciate any help.

Comment: You used the standard method for this type of integral, but did you do it correctly?

Comment: @Bernard, are you saying partial fraction decomposition is standard for  this integral?  I'd like to see your set up.  Perhaps you meant that integration by parts being standard?

Comment: Not exactly. The standard method consists in the substitution you did, so that the integral comes down to the integral of a rational function. Now integrals of rational functions use partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You idea was very good.

Considering$$I=\int \sqrt\frac{x-1}{3-x}\,dx$$ $$u= \sqrt\frac{x-1}{3-x}\implies x=\frac{3 u^2+1}{u^2+1}\implies dx=\frac{4 u}{\left(u^2+1\right)^2}du$$ So $$I=\int\frac{4 u^2}{\left(u^2+1\right)^2}dt=4\int\frac{du}{u^2+1}-4\int\frac{du}{\left(u^2+1\right)^2}$$ The first one is simple; for the second one, use integration by parts.

I suppose that you did not work enough the simplification of $dx$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Forget about the integral limits for a while. Use substitution with $u=3-x$ to get $-\int \sqrt{\frac{2}{u}-1}\,du$. Then use integration by parts $\int wdv=wv-\int v \,dw$ with $w=\sqrt{\frac{2}{u}-1}$ and $dv=du$. You will get bunch of terms but one looks like 
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}\sqrt{2-u}}\,du $$ 
But this is 
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2u-u^2}}\,du =\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{-(u-1)^2+1}}\,du $$ 
For this integral use substitution with $y=u-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint...first substitute $u=2-x$ then substitute $u=\cos 2\theta$

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the integrand as $$\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{(3-x)(x-1)}}=\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}}$$

Then we can split this and write it as $$-\frac 12\int\frac{4-2x}{\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}}dx+\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}}dx$$

So the primitive is $$-\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}+\arcsin (x-2)$$

Now apply the limits.

Comment: The first line would be enough as a hint I guess. This problem could be a homework problem and we don't want to give full solutions here